# What's the meaning of "get the car"?

Tags: meaning

The main text:

> The movie ended. We told Grandma good night.*It was a balmy summer
>   evening, perfect for the motorcycle*, Tom said I should ride home
>   with him, we’d ***get the car*** tomorrow. He revved the engine, waiting for me
>   to climb on. I took a step toward him, then remembered the math book on
>   Grandma’s table. “You go,” I said. “I’ll be right behind you.”

What's the meaning of **get the car** here?

Comment: You should tell us where this came from. See [Why you should cite your source](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/get)

**get**

> to go somewhere and bring back someone or something

For the context that you provide, they had two vehicles, a car and a motorcycle, but they rode home using just one of them, the motorcycle, leaving the other. They have to return at some point in the future (tomorrow) to recover the car.

> go to Grandma's house (somewhere) to bring back the car
>   (something)

Comment: I added some more text. It shows that Tom has a motorcycle. Does he suggest both of them go by his motorcycle and tomorrow  bring back the car?

Comment: Yes, he does. Updated my answer.